# Setting width of a div with CSS not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a survey for a client. Everything good however when I visit the survey on mobile devices (small screen sizes) some of the survey is popping out of the screen which makes it unusable.

I tried to change the size of the survey with ***width*** but it doesnt change.
I've read that it might depends on inline, but still no change.

The Website (made with Wordpress):
https://survey.xs-sol.com/

Here's some pictures:

Everythings fine
[image: Here's everything fine]

Here's missing some survey
(this is 1 to 1 copy from mobile, so the cut is the issue)
[image: Here's a lot missing]

What is it, that triggers the issue?

Comment: What theme are you using? It's possible that there might be styles for mobile/smaller screens that you need to overwrite instead.

Comment: I use twenty sixteen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problematic is the selectbox under "What is your working environment?" - the second option "Shop (Food, El..." is quite big, so on small screens where there is not enough space, scrollbar appears.

Add `select { width: 100%; }` to your styles to solve this issue.